# Removing all variables before each run of a python program

Tags: python

I have a program that runs daily and exits. So every time it runs in the night variables are assigned to it and would be there for the life time of the program and then deleted once the program finishes. Now i have another script that is simulating the daily runs just this script is doing it all in one go. So i want to be able to delete all the variables etc. I am using this but this even deletes the object values stored on the current script which i do not want to do. What is the best way of doing this in python?

```
sys.modules[__name__].__dict__.clear()
```

Comment: if the no of variables is less you can put them in a list and `for var in variables: del var`

Comment: if you know other that you want to delete var x, you just do `del x`

Comment: you can also wrap the nightly script in a class. Create an object use it. delete the object once you are done with it. that way each object will have their own values for variables.

Comment: "The best way" is to design your program with class or function and python will delete the local variables when you finish using them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the conditions of your scripts, you can **delete** or **assign** your variables to zero or ***default amount*** before the main block executed:

```
variable1 = 0
```

or bash operator:

```
list_of_variable = [a, b, c]
for i in list_of_variable:
    i = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use:

```
del(var1,var2,var3,etc)
```

**Or** assign None to them

```
vars_all = [var1, var2]

for vars in vars_all:
    vars = None
```

**Or** assign 0 to them

```
vars_all = [var1, var2]

for vars in vars_all:
    vars = 0
```